# Rendering a 1 dimensional array as a grid?

Tags: java

I can draw a two dimension array in a grid like so:

```
int[][] foo = new int[10][10];

// assume the array is full of data
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        g.setColor(new Color(foo[x][y] & 255, foo[x][y] & 255, foo[x][y] & 255));
        g.fillRect(x * 50, y * 50, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can do the same with
a 1 dimensional array? Is there any magical
math operations I can do each iteration, 
or do I have to fill it into a 2d array
manually?

Comment: Also it looks like your not even using your array...

Comment: What is the desired outcome of the array grid using 1D?

Comment: 10x10 entries equal 100 entries. So use a 100 entries 1D array...

Comment: use % the modulo operator (which gives the remainder of a division) and the / division operator

Comment: @m_callens I'm doing it because I want to take a 1 dimensional array (a list of how many files are in a directory that java gives you from listFiles()) and display them as a grid like [this](http://i.imgur.com/EfWP7tD.png). Luckily, what HopefullyHelpful put worked so I'm just waiting till I can accept his answer. I put in an example in my question from my head, so there were some mistakes, but I didn't want to paste in files of code from my project.

Comment: @brso05 woops I must've messed up the example

Comment: @brso05 erm actually, I think I was right the first time with `width * y + x`. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: @brso05 It depends on how you lay out the single-dimensional array. The way I laid it out in my answer, (x=0, y=1) is indeed at index 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the remainder and the division. If you increase the index the remainder will go up by 1 each time up to width-1 and then be 0 again. Your division value will go up by 1 if the index/width reaches the next full division.

```
int width=10;
for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect((index%width) * 50, (index/width) * 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Think about a grid with values assigned sequentially, like this:

```
[ 0] [ 1] [ 2] [ 3]
[ 4] [ 5] [ 6] [ 7]
[ 8] [ 9] [10] [11]
[12] [13] [14] [15]
```

Each row starts at 4r, and each column within that row just adds an offset. So, index = 4r + c, where r and c are both 0-based. The coefficient 4 comes from the width of each row; since each row has 4 elements, the start of each row is 4 greater than the start of the previous row.

In Java terms, you'd have:

```
int index = width * y + x;
int f = foo[index];
```

For instance, the cell `[14]` above is at x=2, y=3 (remember, these values are 0-indexed). Plugging in width=4 we get:

```
index = width * y + x
      =   4   * 3 + 2
      =   14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want print a 1-dim array in a grid of X elements each lines, you can do something like this

```
int[][] foo = new int[20];

for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    if(x % 5 == 0 && x != 0) //so when x is 5, 10, 15, 20
        //go in a new line
}
```

so you will have something like

```
foo[0]  foo[1]  foo[2]  foo[3]  foo[4] 
foo[5]  foo[6]  foo[7]  foo[8]  foo[9] 
foo[10] foo[11] foo[12] foo[13] foo[14] 
foo[15] foo[16] foo[17] foo[18] foo[19]
```